# C# XML Parse double tag to list

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have a problem. I have the following class to parse my XML to:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "picture")]
public class SetPicture
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "quantity")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sizes")]
    public List<Size> Sizes { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "set")]
public class Set
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "pictures")]
    public List<SetPicture> Pictures { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sets")]
public class Sets
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "set")]
    public List<Set> Set { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sets")]
    public Sets Sets { get; set; }
}
```

And I receive the following XML:

```
<data>
   <sets>
      <set>
         <name>Set A</name>
         <price>13.9</price>
         <pictures>
            <picture>
               <id>4</id>
               <name>Potret2.jpg</name>
               <size>13 x 18 mat</size>
               <price>6.95</price>
               <quantity>2</quantity>
            </picture>
            <picture>
               <id>5</id>
               <name>Potret2Pasfoto.jpg</name>
               <size>13 x 18 mat</size>
               <price>6.95</price>
               <quantity>1</quantity>
            </picture>
         </pictures>
      </set>
   </sets>
</data>
```

But after parsing the XML to the Class, I get an empty `List<SetPicture> Pictures`. I think I know what is going wrong, because I parse the tag `<pictures>` to the list, but I need to parse the elements `<picture>` to the list.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `[XmlElement(ElementName = "pictures")]` to `[XmlElement(ElementName = "picture")]`

Comment: Nope, already tried that, but that still returns me an empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 - Change the `Set` class. Create new class with `Pictures` having list of `Picture`

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "set")]
public class Set
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "pictures")]
    public Pictures Pictures { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "pictures")]
public class Pictures
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "picture")]
    public List<SetPicture> Picture { get; set; }
}
```

Method 2 - Change the `XmlElement` to `XmlArray`

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "set")]
public class Set
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("pictures")]
    [XmlArrayItem("picture", typeof(SetPicture))]
    public List<SetPicture> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```